# How to define "N" number of parameter based on the value of "N"

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I use xslt 2.0. I have a parameter named "N" which has an integer value.

```
Eg: <xsl:param name="N" select="5">
```

Now I want to define "N" number of parameters which are as follows:

```
<xsl:param name="car1"/>
<xsl:param name="car2"/>
<xsl:param name="car3"/> and so on...till
<xsl:param name="carN"/>
```

So in this example since the value of N is 5, I want to create the following parameters:

```
<xsl:param name="car1"/>
<xsl:param name="car2"/>
<xsl:param name="car3"/>
<xsl:param name="car4"/>
<xsl:param name="car5"/>
```

The number of parameters must be generated dynamically based on value "N" and not hard coded in xsl.Also even I can use xslt 1.0 if this situation demands to use it.
I may also pass the N value from java using

```
transformer.setparameter("N","5");
```

Comment: Parameters are a tool to be used for a purpose, not a goal by themselves. What is your purpose here? -- P.S. If you are using XSLT 2.0, don't tag your question as XSLT 1.0. There's nothing you can do in XSLT 1.0 that cannot be done in XSLT 2.0.

Comment: You cannot generate configurable number of parameters in XSLT2.0 at runtime. Parameters should be predefined. You can use <xsl:choose> to call templates with different number of parameters.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers.Will try to use <xsl:choose> to call templates with different number of parameters.

Comment: Please explain why you want multiple parameters. This should never be necessary. **Hint:** You can pass multiple values in one parameter. Probably you want this instead. **More general hint 1:** If you find yourself in a situation where you want numbered variables (`car1` .. `carN`) you always have an error in your approach, no matter what programming language you are in. **More general hint 2:** If you duplicate your code you have an error your approach as well.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should be writing a stylesheet that generates a stylesheet (sometimes called a meta-stylesheet). This isn't difficult, because XSLT uses XML syntax it can readily be used to create or transform stylesheets. However, whether this is the right approach to your problem is an open question, since you haven't told us what your problem is.